# Cygwin's MinTTY behaving strangely with case sensitive names

Tags: windows-10, cygwin, mintty

Cyginw's MinTTY sorts files incorrectly on:

- ls -al

Example:

```
S@DESKTOP-SCRPN /cygdrive/c/Users/S/Downloads
$ ls -al
total 153
drwx------+ 1 S      None     0 Feb  5 17:11 .
drwxrwxr-x+ 1 SYSTEM SYSTEM   0 Feb  3 11:21 ..
-rwx------+ 1 S      None     0 Feb  5 17:05 C.txt
drwx------+ 1 S      None     0 Feb  5 17:08 Pictures
-rwx------+ 1 S      None     0 Feb  5 17:05 a.txt
-rwx------+ 1 S      None     0 Feb  5 17:05 b.txt
-rwx------+ 1 S      None     0 Feb  5 17:05 d.txt
-rwx------+ 1 S      None   282 Sep 26 22:16 desktop.ini
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 S      None     0 Feb  5 17:10 output
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 S      None     0 Feb  5 17:11 upload
```

It always puts uppercase names first.

- `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | sort -zr` sorts incorrectly and gives the same result as `... | sort -z`.
- Tab (filename completion).

I can understand **why** this happens. I've searched thoroughly and understand how there are differences in handling case sensitivity between Linux and Windows. I have found a workaround for the sort command, I can use `... | sort -fr` and it fixes the issue. But I want to ask, is there any way to fix this issue fundamentally?

Comment: I can not replicate. My `ls` produces a not case sensitive order

Comment: Well that's weird, I don't even know where I should look for a solution.

Comment: From its info documentation :  `By default, the output is sorted alphabetically, according to the locale settings in effect.` for me it is `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`

Comment: Ah, I see, I remember changing the locale in the settings now, that must have been the culprit.